# PyQt: is there an better way to set objectName in code?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When you use Qt_Designer or Qt_Creator to design a form, objectName for any given widget is always set to something. But if you create a widget in code AND you need the objectName later, you have to assign it explicitly. So then the widget assignment takes at least two lines of code. This seems very inelegant.

Example:

```
button1 = QPushButton('button caption')   # at this point objectName is some kind of empty string
button1.setObjectName('button1')
```

If you need to find the widget later (i.e. with findChild), you must have objectName set, otherwise you're out of luck.

Is there some way to automatically set objectName without extra lines of code? I looked at the [PyQt5 Reference Guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/) and could not find such a feature. A [similar question was asked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160604/pyqt-gui-with-setobjectname-on-all-components-to-enable-functional-testing) on Code Review, but got no answers. Two lines of code isn't the end of the world, but it seems redundant. Somehow I'm required to assign this name twice once for Python (first line) and again for Qt.

Comment: it would be more convenient  for the ***default*** to be that the Python object had the same "name" as the Qt objectName. This is the case when you use uic on a .ui file. uic does it for you. Could there be a convenience function in uic (or somewhere else) that would allow me to create widgets dynamically in code --*in one line* -- that have objectName assigned?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, regarding QPushButton declaration, I've revised my code snippet so that the text() property is not the same as the name. In my ideal world, if I have button1 = QPushButton(), the objectName would be button1. I was hoping there was an automagic way to do this that I was not aware of.

Comment: `QPushButton('Text', objectName='foo')`

Comment: PS: a much better solution is to avoid using `objectName` and simply do `self.foo = QPushButton('Text')`. Then there's no need to use `findChild` at all.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I use findChild in my form resize code. And for that, I don't want to hard code every control name. I just go by widget type and change font sizes, indicator sizes according to the widget.

Comment: So I was right - you don't need the object-name at all (since you're only using the class). However, if you do set an object-name, you ***must*** hard-code it somewhere, so you might as well use an attribute (which is much more convenient). The `findChild` approach has its uses, but it is the wrong choice for accessing individual items. (PS: Qt Designer automatically sets both the object-name and the attribute).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass `objectName` as a keyword argument when creating the button, like so:

```
button1 = QPushButton('button caption', objectName='button1')
```

This can extend this to any Qt property during initialization:

```
button1 = QPushButton(text='button caption', objectName='button1', icon=icon1)
```

Moreover, signals can be connected when constructing an object, too:

```
button1 = QPushButton(text='button caption', objectName='button1', clicked=someMethod)
```

The added named argument is equivalent to `button1.clicked.connect(someMethod)`.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know you could do this for any property. Cool. It's still (in my view) excessive typing but it works.

Comment: I am trying to do this, but PyCharm detects an error, it says Expected type Union, got QWidget instead

Answer (score 0):

```py
import uuid

# Decorator for automatically setting object name as class name + UUID
def set_unique_name(class_type):
    original_init = class_type.__init__

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        auto_set_name = kwargs.pop('auto_set_name', True)  # Get the auto_set_name parameter from kwargs, default to True
        original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if auto_set_name:
            class_name = self.__class__.__name__  # Get the class name
            unique_name = f"{class_name}_{str(uuid.uuid4())}"  # Class name + UUID
            self.setObjectName(unique_name)

    class_type.__init__ = new_init
    return class_type

# Use the decorator to set object names
@set_unique_name
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    pass

@set_unique_name
class MyButton(QPushButton):
    pass

@set_unique_name
class MyGroupBox(QGroupBox):
    pass

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QGroupBox
    
    app = QApplication([])
    window = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
    
    widget = MyWidget(window)
    button_with_name = MyButton(window, auto_set_name=True)  # Automatically set object name
    button_without_name = MyButton(window, auto_set_name=False)  # Do not automatically set object name
    group = MyGroupBox(window)
    
    layout.addWidget(widget)
    layout.addWidget(button_with_name)
    layout.addWidget(button_without_name)
    layout.addWidget(group)
    
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).